# STM32 Boot pin functions

Tags: stm32, boot

I have a question about the BOOT pin performance of the STM32G031.

In the datasheet says that upon reset, the boot pin (PA13) is established at the beginning as the picture shows.
[image]

I wanna know if it is only at the beginning of the reset and then I can use the BOOT pin as an ADC pin???

In the stm32g031 that boot pin automatically changes to SW after boot but we don't need to debug

Answer (score 2):

BOOT pins may behave a bit differenly on the different STM32 series, so you should refer to the reference manual of your part. But generaly, yes, if BOOT pin is shared with GPIO - it can be used as GPIO afterwards.

See quote from STM32F42x RM (part 2.4 Boot configuration):
[image: quote from STM32F42x RM]